# Traversing the DOM to determine the existance of a child element and outputting the path from Parent to Child using JavaScript / ES6

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I have a strange question here, but I wanted to ask the community. I was asked by a colleague a question regards DOM structure. He wanted to know the best way to determine that a parent node/element contains a child node/element and how could the DOM path / selector from parent to child be collected / determined. Say for example we have a DOM like so, with a parent node with id `parentItem` and child node with id `childItem`

```
<body>
<div id="parentItem">
  <div>
    <div>I am some text</div>
    <div>Today is Wednesday, 15th May, 2019</div>
    <div>
      <article>
        <h1>Article 1</h1>
        <img src="/img.png">
        <div>I am a sibling</div>
        <div id="childItem">I am the Child</div>
      </article>
      <article>
        <h1>Article 2</h1>
        <img src="/img2.png">
        <div>I am another Article</div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>I am a footer</div>
</div>
</body>
```

So, I said that the best way to determine the relationship is to determine that the child node exists within the parent and work our way up the DOM till we get to the parent. I wrote the following function to check that the relationship exists, then work up the DOM from the child making an array of the Node path and the index of the node item in regards to its parent. I wrote this:

```
function childRelationship(parent, child) {
  if(document.getElementById(parent).contains(document.getElementById(child))) {
    let el = document.getElementById(child);
    const end = document.getElementById(parent).id;
    const pathArray = [];


    while(el.parentNode && el.id !== end) {
      let chosenIndex = ([...el.parentNode.children].filter((node) => node.tagName === el.tagName).indexOf(el));
      chosenIndex = `[${chosenIndex}]`;
      pathArray.unshift(el.tagName + chosenIndex);
      el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return 'Exists: ' + pathArray.join(' > ');
  } else {
    return 'No Child Exists Within Parent';
  }
}
```

When I run `childRelationship('parentItem','childItem')` the output using the example DOM is `Exists: DIV[0] > DIV[2] > ARTICLE[0] > DIV[1]`.

Everything is great but I have to ask is there a better or more elegant way of a) determining the path between parent and child (like a ES6 method)? and b) determining the index of the correct DOM item as the solution of `([...el.parentNode.children].filter((node) => node.tagName === el.tagName).indexOf(el));` seems too complex. Is there any easier way to get the path and index without traversing backwards?

If this is a bad question or I have worded it badly please say so and I will rework my question.

Comment: Well it wouldn't be an ES6 feature, because the DOM has nothing to do with ES6 (and vice-versa).  Whether there's a "better" way depends on what "better" means subjectively. For example, taking advantage attributes (id, class) of intermediate nodes might make the paths less fragile.

Comment: There are many different ways to express a "path". For the format you have chosen, your approach and code is fine.

Comment: Thanks! Good point, by better I mean less complex and potentially less code. Coverting to array, then filtering seems to be a complex way of getting the index. Also as `.contains` lets us see if a parent has a child I was wondering if there was some way of magically producing the path between the two nodes.

Comment: From your colleague's question, I wonder if `document.querySelector('#parentItem #childItem')` isn't enough. Are you sure they need the whole path and every Elements in there?

Comment: I doubt they need it - it was a hypothetical question as far as I was concerned, I was just curious if my solution could be bettered or improved